# have a string in c++, need help to split it

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<string>temp;
    int m = 0;
    string strOperand = "10   7  5.0   *   -";
    string strCurData = ""; 
    for (int i = 0; i < strOperand.size(); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(strOperand[i]) || strOperand[i] == '.')
        {
            strCurData.push_back(strOperand[i]);
        }
        else
        if (!isdigit(strOperand[i]) && strOperand[i] != '.'){
            if (strOperand[i] == ' ')
            {
                temp[m] = strCurData;
                strCurData = "";
                m++;
            }
            else
            if (strOperand[i] == '+' || strOperand[i] == '-' || strOperand[i] == '*' || strOperand[i] == '/' || strOperand[i] == '%' || strOperand[i] == '^')
            {
                temp[m] = strOperand[i];
                m++;
            }
            else
            if (strOperand[i]=='\0')
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << m;
}
```

i want to split the string to a vector, but it turns to be a error warning that vector subscript is out of range, i am really worry about this, can someone please help me, thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: There's far simpler ways of doing this..

Comment: Looks like you're trying to add new elements to the vector by accessing `temp[m]`, when `m` >= the current size of the vector. The class doesn't behave that way - you need to use `insert` or `push_back` to add new elements.

Comment: I am pretty sure that if (!isdigit(strOperand[i]) && strOperand[i] != '.') is always true

Comment: `if (strOperand[i]=='\0')`  std::string does not use null to terminate a string.  What exactly are you trying to do with this code?  I bet it could be done with just a few lines of code, much shorter (and safer) than what you've posted.

Comment: `string strOperand = "10   7  5.0   *   -"; string strCurData = ""; std::istringstream strm(strOperand); while (strm >> strCurData) temp.push_back(strCurData);`  Is this what you're trying to do with all of the code you posted?

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is empty, yet you access its  nonexistent  elements by index. The behavior you describe is as expected.

Comment: so how can I change this to let it work

Comment: @crlyw You may want to use one of the functions that inserts an element into the vector. `push_back` is a good candidate.